# How to deal with cases where problems 'fix themselves'?

Tags: discussion, questions

What to do when having a question [like this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4719/libcanberra-is-failing-to-build), where I have no idea what fixed the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it can be determined that the question *never* actually contained a problem, it should be deleted (or flagged for moderator attention to delete). That is not *always* the case. I just wrote about this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72614/what-should-be-done-if-somebody-asks-a-question-but-later-says-nevermind-my-mis/72626#72626):

> I see two scenarios:
>
> 1. **The user resolved the problem themselves before receiving an answer.**
>    (i.e. *"Oh, nevermind. I figured it out myself."*)
>    Solution: The author's need for the answer is irrelevant. If it's a *valid* question, it should be left and answered for others who come after. Hopefully the author will offer their solution, but the author is only one person. The future audience who may benefit from the question is much larger.
> 2. **The question was rendered invalid or irrelevant.**
>    (i.e. *"Oops, silly me. I had the wrong setting. Nevermind!"*)
>    Solution: If the question was rendered invalid or no longer applies to the situation, it should be flagged for moderator attention. Comment that the user should have deleted this themselves. But, either way, there is no further purpose for it being on the system, it should be deleted.

Your situation seems more applicable to scenario (2). There's a comment that specifically references the occasional *"Hmm... I rebooted my computer and now my code works."*